# is File.Encrypt Method safe? Encrypt File Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, encryption

I have a Windows Phone application which create and has access to personal data in a txt file. I want something like:
The application asks the user to insert his password , and if it is correct , it decrypts runtime the data and makes the data accessible.

What's the right way to encrypt this data?
I search something that is simple to use and is very safe. I've tried to search in the web and i've found this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.encrypt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But is it safe? There's anybody that have used it? How it works?

Sorry for my poor english. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think File.Encrypt is available on Windows Phone. I think you're looking for something more like [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh487164%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole article about encrypting data on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh487164%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Just use `ProtectedData.Protect` and `ProtectedData.Unprotect`. Both methods take the data and salt as paremeters, so use the user`s password as salt.